# IDEA IDE - disable inspection for one file

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Is there a way to disable inspection for one file opened in the editor? I occasionally open large library file in the editor to inspect its source code, and don't want IDEA to run inspections on this particular file.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use Hector the Inspector guy. You can access it by clicking on "guy in a hat" icon in Status Bar or via `Code | Configure Current File Analysis...` from the main menu.

Once there you can move the "Highlighting Level" slider from "Inspections" to "Syntax"  .. or even "None" in case of a large or complex file.

[image]

Notes:

1. Settings here affect current file only (excludes "Power Save Mode" option)
2. Depending on a file, you may have multiple sliders (e.g. in `.php` file you will see separate sliders for HTML and PHP languages: this may change depending on some other settings):

   [image]

**P.S.**
If your file is actually part of the library (PHP or JavaScript; "Library" in terms of IDE, of course) then they by default should not have inspections enabled in them:

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2021-06-11:**

Hector the Inspector has been removed from the status bar since 2020.2 version or so. You can get it back by installing [Hector the Inspector plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15111-hector-the-inspector) from `Settings/Preferences | Plugins`

Comment: Has Hector been removed? I don't have that icon anymore. 2021.1.2

Comment: @Jacob Yes, for almost a year now 9since 2020.2). You can use `Code | Configure Current File Analysis...` from main menu to get to the same screen. Or if you wish -- install a plugin for that: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15111-hector-the-inspector

Answer (score 2):

You can set scope for your project and run inspections only for selected scopes.

[image]

@see [Inspection severity and scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/inspections.html)

Comment: yeah, I know about scopes, can you please demonstrate how this can be applied on ad hoc files?

Comment: @Maximus you can't turn off inspection on single file. You can move this file to custom directory and exclude directory from scope. Also you can in `file types` exclude file from project, but i think it's not what you want.

Comment: ok, thanks, let's wait to see if someone knows a better way. Anyways, thanks for the suggestions, I upvoted